# How do I find out the attributes of a 'user' in my Amplify-React project?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So some of the default code that is provided when you create an Amplify-React app looks like this:

`<Heading level={1}>Hello {user.username}</Heading>`

I have tried searching all over my project's files to find out what attributes 'user' has. Clearly it has a 'username' attribute, but what I'd like to change is the heading so that it says "Hello {user.firstname}". Firstname doesn't work so I was wondering where in my project I can find the attributes that a user has so that I can change the heading to their first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Auth.currentUserInfo()` should return you an object like this:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "email": "MY EMAIL ADDRESS",
    "email_verified": true,
    "sub": "INTERNAL USERID: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
  },
  "id": "us-east-1:XXXX",
  "username": "MY USERNAME"
}
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/three-methods-to-get-user-information-in-aws-amplify-authentication-e4e39e658c33)

As this function is asynchronous, be sure to `await` it when setting it to a variable.

Comment: You're welcome. There are lots of other methods on `Auth` you can use for different use-cases too.